# What is the best way to delete duplicate records after a raw import of text files to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I imported a lot of records and need to be able to delete duplicates that might have been imported by mistake.

[image]

On a separate note, I would like to be able to query all records for specific keywords. I am new to MongoDB and was hoping someone could help with a query or two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to remove duplicate documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184099/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove duplicates based on a `key`, you can create an `index` on the collection and enable `dropDups` like this,

```
db.yourCollection.ensureIndex({'myKey' : 1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
```

The following `index` will keep the first unique document and drop any duplicates followed by that.

**Note: `dropDups` will not work in MongoDB 3.0 or above. If you're a new version, please follow this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184099/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb/33364353#33364353) instead.**

As to query records for specific keywords, you can use both `find` (with or without **regex**) and MongoDB's `text search`.

You can find more information on MongoDB **find** [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and on **Text Search** [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

Comment: My unique key is the content. I am looking to see how the query would cycle through each string in the db.

Comment: Please be more clear on the question by updating it.