# How to set unique constraint for field in document nested in array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I have a collection of documents in MongoDB that looks like:

```
{"_id": 1, "array": [{"id": 1, "content": "..."}, {"id": 2, "content": "..."}]}
{"_id": 2, "array": [{"id": 1, "content": "..."}, {"id": 2, "content": "..."}, {"a_id": 3, "content": "..."}]}
```

and I want to ensure that there is no duplicate `array.id` within each document. So the provided example is ok, but the followign is not:

```
{"_id": 1, "array": [{"id": 1, "content": "..."}, {"id": 1, "content": "..."}]}
```

My question is how to do this (preferably in `PyMongo`).

**EDIT**

What I tried was the following code that I thought would create key on `(_id, array.id)` but if you run it this does not happen:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, ASCENDING

client = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017)
database = client["test_db"]
collection = database["test_collection"]
collection.drop()

collection.create_index(keys=[("_id", ASCENDING),
                              ("array.id", ASCENDING)],
                        unique=True,
                        name="new_key")

document = {"array": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}
collection.insert_one(document)

collection.find_one_and_update({"_id": document["_id"]},
                               {"$push": {"array": {"id": 1}}})

updated_document = collection.find_one({"_id": document["_id"]})

print(updated_document)
```

which outputs (note that there are two objects with `id = 1` in the `array`). I would expect to get an exception.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5eb51270d6d70fbba739e3b2'), 'array': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 1}]}
```

Comment: Please  see this similar issue and answer [Eliminate duplicates in MongoDB with a specific sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508338/eliminate-duplicates-in-mongodb-with-a-specific-sort)

Comment: @prasad_ In the post you mentioned it is only described how to ensure you have no duplicates when you do the query, but I want the database to check if there are no duplicates if I for example insert a new value. Basically what I would like to achieve is set an "index" on `(_id, id)`

Comment: Inserting (pushing) into an array is an update operation. Make sure your update's query condition checks that the `id` doesn't exist in the array of sub-documents. You can also set indexes on array fields - these are called as [Multikey Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html). See the sub-topic in the link: _Unique Multikey Index_

Comment: @prasad_  I think the Multikey indexes is what I am looking for. I tried it but with no luck. So from the documentation I would assume that I should set the index as `db.coll.createIndex( { "array.id": 1 } )` correct? I tried this and it does not work.

Comment: Please explain what you meant by _"I tried this and it does not work."_.

Comment: @prasad_ I added to the question what I tried exactly. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behaviour - with Multikey Indexes. See this note [Unique Multikey Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html#unique-multikey-index). It says that the uniqueness applied across documents (not the array elements within a document). Hence, there is no exception.

Comment: I see. So if I understand it correctly there is no way how to set index (or some condition) that would enforce the uniqueness within the document, right? (Other than check this explicitly when creating the document or when inserting into it.)

Comment: Totally correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer. (If you post it as one I will accept it).

Comment: Sure, I will post little later on. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if I understand it correctly there is no way how to set index (or
>   some condition) that would enforce the uniqueness within the document,
>   right? (Other than check this explicitly when creating the document or
>   when inserting into it.)

Yes. Please see the following two scenarios about using the unique index on an array field with embedded documents.

[Unique Multikey Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html#unique-multikey-index) (index on embdeed document field within an array):

> For unique indexes, the unique constraint applies across separate
>   documents in the collection rather than within a single document.
>
> Because the unique constraint applies to separate documents, for a
>   unique multikey index, a document may have array elements that result
>   in repeating index key values as long as the index key values for that
>   document do not duplicate those of another document.

**First Scenario:**

```
db.arrays.createIndex( { _id: 1, "array.id": 1}, { unique: true } )

db.arrays.insertOne( { "_id": 1, "array": [ { "id": 1, "content": "11"}, { "id": 2, "content": "22"} ] } )

db.arrays.insertOne( { "_id": 2, "array": [ { "id": 1, "content": "1100"}, { "id": 5, "content": "55"} ] } )

db.arrays.insertOne( {"_id": 3, "array": [ {"id": 3, "content": "33"}, {"id": 3, "content": "3300"} ] } )
```

All the three documents gets inserted without any errors.

As per the note on ***Unique Multikey Index***, above, the document with `_id : 3` has two embedded documents within the array with same `"array.id"`value: `3`.

Also, the uniqueness is enforced on two keys of the compound index `{ _id: 1, "array.id": 1}` and there were duplicate `"array.id"` values across the documents also ( the `_id` values `1` and `2`).

**Second Scenario:**

```
db.arrays2.createIndex( { "array.id": 1 }, { unique: true } )

db.arrays2.insertOne( { "_id": 3, "array": [ { "id": 3, "content": "33" }, { "id": 3, "content": "330"} ] } )
db.arrays2.insertOne( { "_id": 4, "array": [ { "id": 3, "content": "331" }, { "id": 30, "content": "3300" } ] } )
```

The first document with `_id : 3` gets inserted successfully. The second one has an error: `"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.arrays2 index: array.id_1 dup key: { array.id: 3.0 } "`. This behavior is as expected as per the note ***Unique Multikey Index***.

Comment: If we do like this then it becomes unique at the DB level, I wanted to do it at the document level, having two fields of array

Answer (score 0):

You can do this check on update

```
const doc = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id, 'array.id': { $ne: newID} },
    {
      $push: {
        array: newID
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  );
```