# MongoDB - unique compound index on array of nested documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a compound unique index

```
db.collection("sheets").createIndex(
    {
        'cells.x': 1,
        'cells.y': 1
    },
    { unique: true }
);
```

so I can have documents like this:

```
{
    _id: "xxx",
    name: "sheet 1",
    cells: [{x:0, y:1, sheet_id: "xxx"}, {x:1, y:1, sheet_id: "xxx"}]
}
```

but when I create **2** documents with empty 'cells' array field,
I get this error:

```
(node:23492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.sheets index: cells.x_1_cells.y_1_cells.sheet_id_1 dup key: { cells.x: null, cells.y: null, cells.sheet_id: null }
```

notice the:

> dup key: { cells.x: null, cells.y: null, cells.sheet_id: null }

ofcourse I dont reallt have a { cells.x: null, cells.y: null, cells.sheet_id: null } in the array. it is empty...

if the 'cells' array in one document is not empty, **I can create a seconed document** with an empty 'cells'.

how can I solve this and have more than one empty 'cells' array?

Comment: See the answer in the post: [How to set unique constraint for field in document nested in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655391/how-to-set-unique-constraint-for-field-in-document-nested-in-array/61695467#61695467).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [`Partial Index`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/) that will index only documents that match its query. In this case, match only documents that have a "cell.x" - effectively saying documents which have some elements.

```
  db.sheets.createIndex({ "cells.x": 1, "cells.y": 1 }, 
    { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "cells.x": { $exists: true } } })
```