# Remove duplications from Mongodb collection on multiple key

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

I have a mongodb collection. 
I want to remove duplicate docs if two key fields are duplicated.

```
db.getCollection("collection").aggregate([
{
    // only match documents that have this field
    // you can omit this stage if you don't have missing fieldX
    $match: {"user_id": {$nin:[null]}}  
},
{
    $group: { "_id": "$user_id", "doc" : {"$first": "$$ROOT"}}
},
{
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$doc"}
},
{$out: "collection2"}
],
{allowDiskUse:true}
)
```

The query above works for one key field.
from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184099/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb/44522593#44522593)

for 2 fields, how can I edit it?

Sample collection;

```
   repo_id    user_id       
0  667006     1060
1  667006     1060 #duplicated ! repo_id and user_id
2  667006     2467194
3  667006     21979
```

Desired output;

```
   repo_id    user_id       
0  667006     1060
1  667006     2467194
2  667006     21979
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to change is `$group` stage, now group on unique pairs of `repo_id` & `user_id`.

Try to replace group stage with below :

```
{
   $group: { _id: {repo_id: '$repo_id',user_id: "$user_id"} , doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" } }
}
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1wZ5ZZyOoJD)