# deleting duplicate records from mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is my collection, can you please update me how to write a code to delete duplicate records from  below collection, having  duplicate records in collection, please explain me how to delete the duplicate records from collection.

```
   /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e84200bdf949c00404ed5ff"),
    "area" : "573",
    "bc" : "GER",
    "bd" : "52001450",
    "bg" : "52001450",
    "borg" : "cde5642",
    "bsg" : "51585929",
    "bsgname" : "INFO TECHNOLOGY",
    "consulting" : null,
    "mobilePhoneNumber" : null,
    "cfax" : null,
    "l" : "BERL",
    "cpgr" : null,
    "o" : "S",
    "friendlyCountryName" : "Germ",
    "ctel" : "+49",
    "mail" : "tl2625@ge.at.com",
    "exch" : "204",
    "ext" : "5408",
    "facsimileTelephoneNumber" : null,
    "givenName" : "POMAS",
    "employeeNumber" : "0249527",
    "jt" : "MC",
    "jtname" : "FLEX FORCE ENGINEER IV",
    "sn" : "LEMP",
  
}

/* 2*/

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e84200bdf949c00404ed601"),
    "area" : "573",
    "bc" : "GER",
    "bd" : "52001450",
    "bg" : "52001450",
    "borg" : "cde5642",
    "bsg" : "51585929",
    "bsgname" : "INFO TECHNOLOGY",
    "consulting" : null,
    "mobilePhoneNumber" : null,
    "cfax" : null,
    "l" : "BERL",
    "cpgr" : null,
    "o" : "S",
    "friendlyCountryName" : "Germ",
    "ctel" : "+49",
    "mail" : "tl2625@ge.at.com",
    "exch" : "204",
    "ext" : "5408",
    "facsimileTelephoneNumber" : null,
    "givenName" : "POMAS",
    "employeeNumber" : "0249527",
    "jt" : "MC",
    "jtname" : "FLEX FORCE ENGINEER IV",
    "sn" : "LEMP",
```

Comment: How can you have 2 documents with the same objectId?

Comment: Yes updated experts, thanks.

Comment: on which keys you decide, if the document is duplicate?

Comment: you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33364353/8307456

Comment: on "employeeNumber" : "0249527", how can i write to delete duplicate employees

Comment: you can use the above link for the answer

Answer (score 0):

by next piece of code you can find the duplicated records.
(hint: change `...,` with other fields.)

```
var cursor = db.collection.aggregate(
[
        {
            "$group": {
                '_id': {
                    "area":"$area",
                    ..., # fill here by other fields
                    "sn": "$sn"
            },
            "count": {
                    "$sum": 1
                }
            },
            "assets":{
                  "$push": {"assets_id":"$_id"}
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "count": {
                    "$gt": 1
                }
            }

        }, 
    {
            "$project": {
                "assets": "assets"
            }

        }
    }

]
)
```

then delete result by filtering `_id`:

```
cursor.forEach(function (doc){
...     db.collection.remove({"_id": doc.assets[0].assets_id});
... });
```

now you just need fill `...` with other your fields, like as `area` and `sn` which I filled.

Comment: Thanks experts, can you please update me on the query how needs to be change.

Comment: I edit the answer if you have a question about the `...` comment again.

Comment: thanks experts, if my collection is like: db.getCollection('employeerecords').find({})
 how can i  input above  query...also i wnt to create new collection, add duplicate records and then need to delete for testing.

Comment: `aggregate` method is more complicated than `find,` `find` just find records according to some filters, but aggregation has multi -stage at each step(`find` has one step) you create semi table with new fields, and at the end, you can have attributed fields by `project`! so I suggest you run above command by replacing the name of your collection, and then remove the result Ids.
For creation `db.getCollection('employeerecords').insert({....})` fill `...` with arbitrary field and repeat it, then it insert multi times.

Comment: But duplicate records we can enter into the collections i mean columns and values,  but object ID will be unique rite.