# MongoDB: How to remove duplicate records from a query?

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

Example collections:

**employee**

```
{"FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "SSN" : "123456789", "SALARY" : 30000, "SUPERSSN" : "333445555"}
{"FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "SSN" : "333445555", "SALARY" : 40000, "SUPERSSN" : "888665555"}
{"FNAME" : "Joyce", "LNAME" : "English", "SSN" : "453453453", "SALARY" : 25000, "SUPERSSN" : "333445555"}
{"FNAME" : "Ramesh", "LNAME" : "Narayan", "SSN" : "666884444", "SALARY" : 38000, "SUPERSSN" : "333445555"}
{"FNAME" : "James", "LNAME" : "Borg", "SSN" : "888665555", "SALARY" : 55000, "SUPERSSN" : "", "DNO" : 1 }
{"FNAME" : "Jennifer", "LNAME" : "Wallace", "SSN" : "987654321", "SALARY" : 43000, "SUPERSSN" : "888665555"}
{"FNAME" : "Ahmad", "LNAME" : "Jabbar", "SSN" : "987987987", "SALARY" : 25000, "SUPERSSN" : "987654321"}
{"FNAME" : "Alicia", "LNAME" : "Zelaya", "SSN" : "999887777", "SALARY" : 25000, "SUPERSSN" : "987654321"}
{"FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "SSN" : "123456789", "SALARY" : 30000, "SUPERSSN" : "333445555"}
{"FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "SSN" : "333445555", "SALARY" : 40000, "SUPERSSN" : "888665555"}
{"FNAME" : "Joyce", "LNAME" : "English", "SSN" : "453453453", "SALARY" : 25000, "SUPERSSN" : "333445555"}
{"FNAME" : "Ramesh", "LNAME" : "Narayan", "SSN" : "666884444", "SALARY" : 38000, "SUPERSSN" : "333445555"}
{"FNAME" : "James", "LNAME" : "Borg", "SSN" : "888665555",  "SALARY" : 55000, "SUPERSSN" : "", "DNO" : 1 }
{"FNAME" : "Jennifer", "LNAME" : "Wallace", "SSN" : "987654321",  "SALARY" : 43000, "SUPERSSN" : "888665555"}
{"FNAME" : "Ahmad", "LNAME" : "Jabbar", "SSN" : "987987987",  "SALARY" : 25000, "SUPERSSN" : "987654321"}
{"FNAME" : "Alicia", "LNAME" : "Zelaya", "SSN" : "999887777", "SALARY" : 25000, "SUPERSSN" : "987654321"}
```

**works_on**

```
{ "ESSN" : "123456789", "PNO" : 1, "HOURS" : 32.5 }
{ "ESSN" : "123456789", "PNO" : 2, "HOURS" : 7.5 }
{ "ESSN" : "333445555", "PNO" : 2, "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "ESSN" : "333445555", "PNO" : 3, "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "ESSN" : "333445555", "PNO" : 10, "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "ESSN" : "333445555", "PNO" : 20, "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "ESSN" : "453453453", "PNO" : 1, "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "ESSN" : "453453453", "PNO" : 2, "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "ESSN" : "666884444", "PNO" : 3, "HOURS" : 40 }
{ "ESSN" : "888665555", "PNO" : 20, "HOURS" : 0 }
{ "ESSN" : "987654321", "PNO" : 20, "HOURS" : 15 }
{ "ESSN" : "987654321", "PNO" : 30, "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "ESSN" : "987987987", "PNO" : 10, "HOURS" : 35.5 }
{ "ESSN" : "987987987", "PNO" : 30, "HOURS" : 5.5 }
{ "ESSN" : "999887777", "PNO" : 10, "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "ESSN" : "999887777", "PNO" : 30, "HOURS" : 30 }
```

I want to remove the duplicate records from a "join" of the following MongoDB query:

```
db.employee.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "works_on",    
            localField: "SSN",   
            foreignField: "ESSN",
            as: "works_on_here"  
        }
    },
    {   $unwind:"$works_on_here" },
    {
        $group:{
          _id:"$_id",
          nodes:{
            $addToSet:"$works_on_here"
        }
    },
    {   
        $project:{
            _id : 1,
            FNAME : 1,
            LNAME : 1,
            HOURS : "$works_on_here.HOURS",
        } 
    }
]);
```

The expected outcome is:

```
{ "FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "HOURS" : 32.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Joyce", "LNAME" : "English", "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "FNAME" : "Ramesh", "LNAME" : "Narayan", "HOURS" : 40 }
{ "FNAME" : "James", "LNAME" : "Borg", "HOURS" : 0 }
{ "FNAME" : "Jennifer", "LNAME" : "Wallace", "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "FNAME" : "Ahmad", "LNAME" : "Jabbar", "HOURS" : 5.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Alicia", "LNAME" : "Zelaya", "HOURS" : 30 }
{ "FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "HOURS" : 7.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
```

The actual output is without the "$group" part looks like:

```
{ "FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "HOURS" : 32.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "HOURS" : 7.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Joyce", "LNAME" : "English", "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "FNAME" : "Joyce", "LNAME" : "English", "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "FNAME" : "Ramesh", "LNAME" : "Narayan", "HOURS" : 40 }
{ "FNAME" : "James", "LNAME" : "Borg", "HOURS" : 0 }
{ "FNAME" : "Jennifer", "LNAME" : "Wallace", "HOURS" : 15 }
{ "FNAME" : "Jennifer", "LNAME" : "Wallace", "HOURS" : 20 }
{ "FNAME" : "Ahmad", "LNAME" : "Jabbar", "HOURS" : 35.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Ahmad", "LNAME" : "Jabbar", "HOURS" : 5.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Alicia", "LNAME" : "Zelaya", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Alicia", "LNAME" : "Zelaya", "HOURS" : 30 }
{ "FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "HOURS" : 32.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "John", "LNAME" : "Smith", "HOURS" : 7.5 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
{ "FNAME" : "Franklin", "LNAME" : "Wong", "HOURS" : 10 }
```

I have the two collections 'employee' and 'works_on' and I try to do something like this "[join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-in-mongodb)".

The code with the $group part returns nothing. This should work as the duplicate filter or?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184099/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb#:~:text=General%20idea%20is%20to%20use,we%20retrieved%20from%20findOne%20option.

Refer this

Comment: Updated my question - the $group part doesn't work. Am I doing smth. wrong?

Comment: can you post sample documents of both collection and expected result in your question.

Comment: of course, the question is updated!

Comment: what is the unique field in employee collection, is it `SSN`?

Comment: yes, this is the unique field. Even though the filter could also be made with the document id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `SSN` and get first `FNAME` and `LNAME` fields, if you want other fields you can add same as `FNAME` and `LNANE`
- `$lookup` with `works_on`
- `$project` to show required fields and get total `HOURS` sum using `$sum`

```
db.employee.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$SSN",
      FNAME: { $first: "$FNAME" },
      LNAME: { $first: "LNAME" }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "works_on",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "ESSN",
      as: "HOURS"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      FNAME: 1,
      LNAME: 1,
      HOURS: {
        $sum: "$HOURS.HOURS"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yXkRYTgSjEG)

Comment: Ok this solution works fine. Is this also possible with a projection? I'm trying to write something like a little converter, so I'm looking for a general solution. If I don't want to make basic calculations the projection works, but does it also works with calcculations?
What does the keyword $first?

Comment: yes you can use $project instead of $addFields stage

Comment: What does the keyword $first?

Comment: $group stage will group your root documents by SSN, so virtually it loop inside group stage and so $first means we are selecting first element from grouped root element.

Comment: Can you please offer the solution with $project and $sum? Doesn't work for me...