# Checking for similar records in mongodb across multiple fields.

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In mongodb, I have a collection of people with the schema below. I need to write an aggregation to find possible duplicates in the database by checking:

- If another person with same firstName, lastName & currentCompany exists.
- Or, if another person with the same currentCompany & currentTitle exists.
- Or, if another person has the same email (which is stored as an object in an array)
- Or, if someone else has the same linkedIn/twitter url.

Is there a straightforward way of checking for duplicates based on the above cases w/ a mongodb aggregation? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491920/find-all-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-by-a-key-field) is close to what I'm looking for, but I need to check more than just one key/value.

```
{ _id: 'wHwNNKMSL9v3gKEuz',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  currentCompany: 'John Co',
  currentTitle: 'VP Sanitation',
  emails: 
   [ { address: 'Anais.Grant@hotmail.com',
       valid: true } ],
  urls: 
   { linkedIn: 'http://linkedin.com/johnDoe',
     twitter: 'http://twitter.com/@john', 
   } 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it is using the following
$and, $or, $ne.

Note:- You need to feed one record as input for the conditions to match it with other records for eliminating the duplicates

I have given a sample query which will be filtering your collection for these two criterias, you can add the rest of your conditions to get the final result

- If another person with same firstName, lastName & currentCompany exists.
- Or, if someone else has the same linkedIn/twitter url.

```js
db.yourcollection.find({
  $and: [{
    $or: [{
      firstName: {
        $ne: 'John'
      }
    }, {
      lastName: {
        $ne: 'Doe'
      }
    }, {
      currentCompany: {
        $ne: 'John Co'
      }
    }]
  }, {
    $or: [{
      "urls.linkedIn": {
        $ne: 'http://linkedin.com/Doe'
      }
    }]
  }]
})
```

Comment: I've thought about doing it this way- but my db has grown to thousands of records and checking each one manually in Node is super CPU intensive. Do you know if a Mongo aggregation could do this more efficiently?

Comment: Aggregation framework is faster. More info on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908438/is-mongodb-aggregation-framework-faster-than-map-reduce

Comment: Gotcha- so I'm still quite unsure on how I would implement the above w/ an aggregation.