# MongoDB -- Find duplicate documents by multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a collection with documents that look like the following:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55b377cb66b393427367c3e2"),
        "comment" : "This is a comment",
        "url_key" : "55b377cb66b393427367c3df", //This is an ObjectId from another record in a different collection
}
```

I need to find records in this collection that contain duplicate values for the both the comment AND the url_key.

I can easily generate (using aggregate) duplicate records for the same, single, key (eg: comment), but I can't figure out how to group by/aggregate for multiple keys.

Here's my current aggregation pipeline:

```
db.comments.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: { comment: "$comment" }, uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } } }, { $sort: { count : -1} }, {$limit 10 } ]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all duplicate documents in a MongoDB collection by a key field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491920/find-all-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-by-a-key-field)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it as simple as grouping by multiple keys or did I misunderstand your question?

```
...
{ $group: { _id: { id: "$_id", comment: "$comment" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
{ $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } } },
...
```

Comment: Yikes. I thought I tried this -- you're 100% correct. You can simply add more keys to _id. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ count: { $gte: 1} }` ? Means it has found more than 1 documents with same fields, which are considered as duplicates.

Comment: @SepGH $gte -> greater than or equal

Comment: Oops... my bad :D