# finding all duplicates in mongo db/robomongp

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

Been stuck for almost two weeks, is there anyway with mongo db to find all duplicates in a collection and then delete them? i have +- 66 000 records.also new to mongo so how do i use that whole collection as an array instead of typing all out.

Comment: to find the duplicates you can follow this link->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491920/find-all-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-by-a-key-field

Answer (score 0):

You've been stuck for two weeks on this, so I expect you've tried googling it. Anyhow I found some questions that were similar and that might be of help.

[Find all duplicate documents in a MongoDB collection by a key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491920/find-all-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-by-a-key-field)

[Find duplicate records in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984799/find-duplicate-records-in-mongodb)